# iPod classic 80GB won't charge from usb power adapter

Tags: ipod, usb, power, charging, ipod-classic

iPod classic 80GB 2007 [Model No.:A1238] won't charge from LG usb travel adapter (output 5.0V, 0.85A). It normally charged from [Apple 5W USB Power Adapter [Model No.:A1299]](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MD812B/A/apple-usb-power-adapter) (output 5.0V, 1A), and normally charged from macbook USB port and required just 0.5A for charging.

[image: iPod current required]

Why it won't charge from LG adapter whose output current (0.85A) actually is between laptop USB port (0.5A) and Apple USB Power Adapter (1A)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into the amount of current available from a USB charger when investigating how to charge multiple iPhones / iPads simultaneously.  Below is something I learnt that *might* be relevant.

There are several different ways that a charger can "tell" an iPod how much current it can provide - the iPod can't determine this directly.  If the charger is a computer, it will communicate this through a data transfer (similar to transferring MP3 file data).

But a simple charger won't use this method.  Instead, there are various standards (some proprietary, I believe!) which specify how much current can be provided, by providing certain voltages at the data lines.  USB has four pins: one ground, one power, and two data.  For example, apparently 2.8V on one of the data pins and 2.0V on another means "you can draw up to 1 amp".  See [this link](http://learn.adafruit.com/minty-boost/icharging) for some detail, although I think some of that is out-dated.

I'd guess that the LG adaptor doesn't provide the signalling that the iPod expects.  I don't know a way to resolve this, other than to try a different adaptor - sorry.